# Android studio emulators without Android phones

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

Android studio not showing android emulators

Android studio, Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1
Macos, macOS Sonoma, version 14.0

Below is Flutter project

No list of Android Emulators:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMlQP.png)

Must run from here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbv4r.png)

I expecting android studio to show a list of android emulators, I just need to select
one and run with my codes

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown on (no device selected) is to show devices that are active

You have to click triangle button on device manager before, to see active devices.

If you want to see pixel XL, pixel 3 and nexus X, you have to click that each of triangle button.